# using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock to write a frame 30 times per second

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm using OpenCV to write a video file. For `cv::VideoWriter` to work correctly the call to the write() function has to happen exactly 30 times per second (for a 30fps video). 
I found [this](https://aaka.sh/patel/2013/06/28/live-video-webcam-recording-with-opencv/) code which uses the boost library to achieve this. I want to to the same but using `std::chrono` in my program. This is my implementation:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point prev = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point current = prev;
long long difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(current-prev).count();

while(recording){

    while (difference < 1000000/30){
        current = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(current-prev).count();
    }                   

    theVideoWriter.write(frameToRecord);

    prev = prev + std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration(1000000000/30);
    difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(current-prev).count();                  
}

theVideoWriter.release();
```

I'm not sure if thats the correct way to do this or if there is a more efficient way. Is there anything better than casting the duration to `long long difference`?

Comment: When you say exactly, how exact do you want your timing to be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a basic tenant to working with `chrono`, which goes something like:

> If you use `count()`, and/or you have conversion factors in your
>   `chrono` code, then you're trying too hard.

This is not your fault.  There really is no good `chrono` tutorial and that is my bad, and I've recently decided I need to do something about that.

In your case, I recommend rewriting your code along the lines of the following:

First create a duration unit which represents the period of your frame rate:

```
using frame_period = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 30>>;
```

Now when you say `frame_period{1}`, that means **exactly** 1/30 of a second.

The next thing to note is that `chrono` comparisons are *always* exact, as long as you stay in the chrono system.  `count()` is a "trap door" for escaping out of the chrono system.  Only escape out when you have no other choice.  So...

```
auto prev = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto current = pref;
// Just get the difference, and don't worry about the units for now
auto difference = current-prev;
while(recording)
{
    // Find out if the difference is less than one frame period
    // This comparison will do all the conversions for you to get an exact answer
    while (difference < frame_period{1})
    {
        current = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        // stay in "native units"...
        difference = current-prev;
    }                   
    theVideoWriter.write(frameToRecord);
    // This is a little tricky...
    // prev + frame_period{1} creates a time_point with a complicated unit
    // Use time_point_cast to convert (via truncation towards zero) back to
    // the "native" duration of high_resolution_clock
    using hr_duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration;
    prev = std::chrono::time_point_cast<hr_duration>(prev + frame_period{1});
    // stay in "native units"...
    difference = current-prev;                  
}
theVideoWriter.release();
```

The comments above are overly verbose once you get chrono.  There's more comment than code above.  But the above just works as you intended, with no need for "escaping out" of the chrono system.

**Update**

If you would want to initialize `difference` such that the inner loop won't be executed the first time, you could initialize it to something just *over* `frame_period{1}` instead of to 0.  To do this, [the utilities found here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html) come in handy.  Specifically `ceil`:

```
// round up
template <class To, class Rep, class Period>
To
ceil(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& d)
{
    To t = std::chrono::duration_cast<To>(d);
    if (t < d)
        ++t;
    return t;
}
```

`ceil` is a replacement for `duration_cast` that will round up when the conversion is inexact, as opposed to truncate towards zero.  Now you can say:

```
auto difference = ceil<hr_duration>(frame_period{1});
```

And you are guaranteed that `difference >= frame_period{1}`.  Furthermore, it is known in practice that the duration of high_resolution_clock is nanoseconds, thus you can deduce (or test) that `difference` is actually initialized to 33,333,334ns, which is 2/3 of a nanosecond greater than 1/30 of a second, which equals `frame_period{1}`, which equals 33,333,333+1/3ns.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something better than using count(). This makes sense. My only trouble is that the first time the loop runs it goes directly in to the second while loop since current-prev is 0. How can I avoid this? Before I just set the difference to a higher value than 1/30 of a second. I'm not sure how to do that with `auto difference`

Comment: @isADon: Updated my answer per your comment as the answer wouldn't fit here.

Comment: Added to "no raw deals" list (no raw new/delete/loops/pointers/threads, and now `chrono::count()`)

Comment: I know I'm quite late here but I was wondering two things about this answer:

1) Why are you doing the interval waiting first and only then perform the action, wouldn't it be more correct the other way around (because then it would actually all happen within the interval)?

2) Why are you doing prev += frame_interval{1} instead of prev = current, doesn't that possibly leave out a small time duration between each interval?

Comment: @user2047610:  1) I stuck with the loop structure in the question because I wanted to make the answer more familiar to the OP, and because I believe it will work correctly either way, modulo start up issues (addressed with `ceil`).  2) The intent is to execute the loop at `t0`, `t0+frame{1}`, `t0+frame{2}`, `t0+frame{3}`, etc.  This is instead of: "wait for `frame{1}` at the end of each iteration."  If I were writing the loop from scratch (and perhaps I should have), I would work in terms of time points instead of time durations, and I think that would make it clearer.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Ah true, I guess it depends on whether you want your action to occur in a certain interval or _within_ a certain interval (seems like OP wants the former whereas I want the latter), anyway thanks for the fast response.